# Using netbeans or any IDE to SSH to remote server and access Postgresql database for executing queries on local machine

Tags: java, postgresql, ssh

I want to ssh to a server where authentication is done via a public key

```
ssh ssh_username@server_ipaddress -p port number
```

and after this, want to access a postgresql database

```
psql -h host_name -U user_name database_name
```

How to connect using any IDE

I have tried using

```
sudo ssh -L 6666:127.0.0.1:3306 <your_SSH_username>@<remoteserver.com>
```

What another approach can I use?

Comment: refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java

Comment: If you want debugging help with the Jsch code, then you should post a [mcve] with a good description of the error/problem you're having. If you're asking for other tools or Java code, then your question is off-topic/too broad for SO. Please narrow down what you want to ask.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH library for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to ssh to remote server this way:

```
ssh -L 6666:host_name:5432 ssh_username@server_ipaddress -p portnumber
```

and then connect to database server from your local machine:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6666 -U user_name database_name
```

or using Java with same connection parameters.

Comment: can you explain me purpose of both these steps... thanks

Comment: @gshivam63 First step is a local port forwarding. It forwards any connection to local port 6666 to port 5432 on host_name through ssh. You need this step because you don't have direct access to database server host from your local machine. Second step is just for testing your connection.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh ssh_hostname@ssh_ipaddress -p ssh_portnumber 

psql -h db_hostname -U db_username db_name 
password:xyz
```

Solution:

Terminal

```
$ ssh -L 6666:db_hostname:5432 ssh_hostname@ssh_ipaddress -p ssh_portnumber
```

after that when ssh to server, enter command

```
$ psql -h db_hostname -U db_username db_name
```

To connect from within NetBeans use:

```
Netbeans->Services->Postgresql=> Connect
```

using

- DriverName: PostgreSQL
- Host: localhost
- Database: db_name
- port: 6666
- username: db_username
- password: xyz